# argument of type "float" is not iterable when trying to use for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a countrydf as below, in which each cell in the country column contains a list of the countries where the movie was released.

```
countrydf

id  Country            release_year
s1  [US]                 2020
s2  [South Africa]       2021
s3  NaN                  2021
s4  NaN                  2021
s5  [India]              2021
```

I want  to make a new df which look like this:

```
country_yeardf

Year    US   UK    Japan  India 
1925    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
1926    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
1927    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
1928    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
```

It has the release year and the number of movies released in each country.
My solution is that: with a blank df like the second one, run a for loop to count the number of movies released and then modify the value in the cell relatively.

```
countrylist=['Afghanistan', 'Aland Islands', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'American Samoa', 'Andorra', 'Angola', 'Anguilla', 'Antarctica', ….]
for x in countrylist:
    for j in  list(range(0,8807)):
        if x in countrydf.country[j]:
            t=int (countrydf.release_year[j] )
            country_yeardf.at[t, x] = country_yeardf.at[t, x]+1
```

an error occurred which read:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-225281f8759a> in <module>()
      1 for x in countrylist:
      2  for j in li:
----> 3     if x in countrydf.country[j]:
      4         t=int(countrydf.release_year[j])
      5         country_yeardf.at[t, x] = country_yeardf.at[t, x]+1

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

I don’t know which one is of float type here, I have check the type of countrydf.country[j] and it returned int.
I was using pandas and I am just getting started with it. Can anyone please explain the error and suggest a solution for a df that I want to create?
P/s: my English is not so good so hop you guys understand.

Comment: can you share the output you are expecting

Comment: Aside: why do you convert `range(0, 8807)` to a list?

Comment: @codeholic24 It's in the question, below "I want to make a new df which look like this:"

Comment: If the type of `countrydf.country[j]` is `int`, how do you expect to be able to iterate over it with `if x in`?

Comment: How could a country name be in an integer?

Comment: Can the Country column have more than 1 country in a row? I see that you have a list in each row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `groupby`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['US', 2015], ['India', 2015], ['US', 2015], ['Russia', 2016]], columns=['country', 'year'])

country year
0   US  2015
1   India   2015
2   US  2015
3   Russia  2016
```

Now just groupby country and year and unstack the output:

```
df.groupby(['year', 'country']).size().unstack()
country India   Russia  US
year            
2015    1.0 NaN 2.0
2016    NaN 1.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative ways to achieve this in pandas without loops.

If the Country Column have more than 1 value in the list in each row, you can try the below:

```
>>df['Country'].str.join("|").str.get_dummies().groupby(df['release_year']).sum()

              India  South Africa  US
release_year                         
2020              0             0   1
2021              1             1   0
```

---

Else if Country has just 1 value per row in the list as you have shown in the example, you can use `crosstab`

```
>>pd.crosstab(df['release_year'],df['Country'].str[0])

Country       India  South Africa  US
release_year                         
2020              0             0   1
2021              1             1   0
```